# How to see the light show at Galata Tower?

Tags: turkey, istanbul

I've seen a few videos of light shows being projected onto the [Galata Tower](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galata_Tower) in Istanbul, Turkey. eg.

https://www.facebook.com/watch/?v=158296795064721

I'll be in Istanbul on Nov 25 and Nov 26 of this year. Are these light shows something they do nightly? If so at what times?

My Google searches have been inconclusive. http://www.galatatower.net/ doesn't seem to have any info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Local here.

This light show is originally called [projection mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_mapping) and it was created for a festival called [İstanbul Gençlik Festivali](https://www.istanbulgenclikfestivali.com/) which happened between 2-6 May. This light show continued for 10 days and every night between 21:00 and 00:00 hours and it's over at May 12 midnight.

Unfortunately, you *can't* see it on November.